# Changing value in dataframe to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo

I retrieve the yahoo finance fundamental data using `yahoo_fin` api on Return on Asset (ROA) and Return of Equity (ROE) which gives me the layout format:

```
   Symbol   Attribute   Value   
0       A        ROA       X%
1       A        ROE      XX%
2       B        ROA       Y%
3       B        ROE      YY%
4       C        ROA       Z%
5       C        ROE      ZZ%
```

I did `df.transpose()` but gives me the following layout format:

```
                  0    1    2    3    4    5
Symbol            A    A    B    B    C    C
Attribute         ROA  ROE  ROA  ROE  ROA  ROE 
Value             X%   XX%  Y%   YY%  Z%   ZZ%
```

The ROA and ROE is represented as `value` in the `df`, my goal is to shift these `value` to `column` . My ideal layout format:

```
Symbol   ROA   ROE
A        X%    XX%
B        Y%    YY%
C        Z%    ZZ%
```

I know how to set the index on symbol but would need to first change the `value` in the `df` to `column`. Appreciate any advice, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `pivot`

```
df.pivot('Symbol','Attribute', 'Value')
```

output

```
Attribute   ROA ROE
Symbol      
A   X%  XX%
B   Y%  YY%
C   Z%  ZZ%
```

Comment: `df.columns.name = None`   to remove the 'Attribute'